# A basic combinatorics problem: number of solutions of form $ \pm 1 $ to and additive equationn

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, integers

In my combinatorics and discrete mathematics class I was asked this question which I cannot seem to be able to solve:

> Let us define N variables $ \{ s_k \}_{k=1}^{N} $ each having two possible values $ \pm 1 $ and we are asked to determine the number of possible N distinct solutions to the following equation:
>
> $ \sum_{k=1}^{N} s_k = m $ for an integer m (positive, negative or zero unknown value).

I have not studied this explicitly, how would one find the number of distinct $ \pm 1 $ solutions to an integer equation? I certainly appreciate all kind helpers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: The key is to realize that $\sum_{k=1}^Ns_k$ depends entirely on the number of variables that are $1$. Say that $\ell$ of them are $1$; then

$$\sum_{k=1}^Ns_k=\ell-(N-\ell)=2\ell-N\;.$$

You can easily determine what $\ell$ must be (in terms of $m$) in order for the sum to be $m$. Now ask yourself: in how many different ways can you get exactly that many of the $N$ variables to be $1$ and the rest to be $-1$?

Comment: Thanks Brian. Is this different number the number of distinct subsets to choose $ \ell $ out of N ?

Comment: @Abeer: No, it's not different: that's exactly the number that you want.

Comment: @Abeer: You're welcome.